# Printing elements of a list inside list with spaces

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list `A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

I want to print elements in the following order:

```
1  2  3  
4  5  6  
7  8  9
```

in python3

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What if numbers are greater than or equal to 10?

Comment: Yeah they can be greater than 10 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explain exactly how you want to handle digits >= 10 (that'l' mess up the printing because of an extra character). But here you go:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in A))
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

An explanation:

First, use `map` to cast the `str` type to the `int`s stored in each of `A`'s sublists. Then, use `' '.join` to concatenate with a space as a delimiter each of the now-`str` numbers in each sublist. Finally, since you wanted to print each sublist on a new line, join the entire iterable with `'\n'.join`.

Comment: Just assume all digits are greater than 10

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in A:
    print(x)
```

Pretty simple, x will be A[0] on the first iteration, A[1] on the second and A[2] on the third.

Comment: I don't want the brackets and comma to be printed